# Force Short TextField To Always Be X Characters

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am attempting to use a `IIF()` statement in a query to update a short text field to always be 4 characters.  This is my syntax, but

```
SELECT DISTINCT IIf(Len([User ID] = 1), "000" & [User ID], IIf(Len([User ID] = 2), "00" & [User ID], IIf(Len([User ID] = 3), "0" & [User ID], [User ID]))) AS ST
FROM _TestData;
```

However it seems to be appending 0's to the data regardless of length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be this simple:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Right("000" & [User ID], 4) AS ST
FROM TestData;
```

Comment: Nice answer! Add an extra zero to account for a zero-length string, but that's probably redundant

Answer (score 0):

If `[User ID]` is number, try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Format([User ID], "0000") AS ST
FROM _TestData;
```

**Update**

Missed that the field is short text. In this case

```
SELECT DISTINCT Format(CLng(Nz([User ID],0)), "0000") AS ST
FROM _TestData;
```